# python count down to event (in days and hours)

Tags: python, datetime

Please can someone advise on this, I've tried various methods but don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I just need a countdown from

```
datetime.now()
```

to

```
datetime(2011,05,05)
```

in days hours

Comment: Then tell us what you tried and how it didn't work. If you don't tell us, either (1) we're doomed to make the same mistakes, or (2) we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
delta = datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 5) - datetime.datetime.now()
```

to get a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object describing the remaining time.  The number of remaining days is `delta.days`, the remaining hours `delta.seconds/3600.` or `delta.seconds//3600`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
import datetime

dt  = datetime.datetime
now = dt.now()

# This gives timedelta in days
dt(year=2011,month=05,day=05) - dt(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day)

# This gives timedelta in days & seconds
dt(year=2011,month=05,day=05) - dt(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day, minute=now.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> days_till_doomsday = \
...   (datetime.datetime(2011,05,05) - datetime.datetime.now()).days
>>> days_till_doomsday
154
>>> hours_till_midnight_today = 24 - datetime.datetime.now().hour
>>> hours_till_midnight_today
5
>>> hours_till_doomsday = \
...   (days_till_doomsday * 24) + hours_till_midnight_today
>>> hours_till_doomsday
3701
```

Does this help?